# Is there any known Tanach edition with Yemenite Hebrew "version"?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tanach, publications, yemenite-temani

I know that there is only one Hebrew version of Torah and Tanach in general. What I mean is that is there any known Hebrew Edition for Tanach using yemenite spelling (e.g. Aleph instead of Heh in "Dakah") (while the Publisher is Orthodox and not Israeli) ?

(If the publisher is Israeli, this might cause me a problem in Lebanon.)

Note as requested by msh210:
1-I want to have both Ashkenazi and Yemenite Tanach.
2-I live in Lebanon, having a book published by an Israeli publisher will cause to me a problem.

Comment: mil, note most traditional Ashkenazim spell Daka with an Alef as well. Only in the last few hundred years there's been a shift with more and more people using the Sefardi spelling.

Comment: One place to start: http://jewishyemenites.com/JY_books.html#TAJs

Comment: Here are various editions of  Yemenite version of the Torah (the Taj) most of which have their version of Targum Onkelos, and the haftarot. Unfortunately the publisher appears to be Israeli, but I have not confirmed this. http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=497.

Comment: See also the attempt to add it to Wikitext athough so far there is very little: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%28%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%92'%29#.D7.9E.D7.A7.D7.A8.D7.90.